# Component has Render Method, but does Not Extend React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`Component appears to have a render method, but doesn't extend React.Component. This is likely to cause errors. Change <Test> to extend React.Component instead`

Using the [extends-classes](https://github.com/jarradseers/extends-classes) library causes a react component to fail rendering with the above error. I'd like to compose a class featuring the React.Component methods and some other methods contained in a different class so I can split my code more concisely.

Example:

```
class Test extends classes (React.Component, OtherTestClass) {
}
```

Is there a way to suppress the error or is there some other strategy I should consider?

Comment: Is `OtherTestClass` a component or just a class?

Comment: Originally, it did not extend `React.Component`. Now that it does it still produces the same result.

Comment: ```
import React from "react";

class OtherTestClass extends React.Component {}

export default TestClass;

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have expected this to work to begin with. Let's examine how this `extends-classes` library works.

The `classes` function returns a dummy class that within its constructor goes through all classes listed as arguments to the `classes` function and copies over all functions and properties to the aforementioned dummy class. It then calls the constructor of all classes.

tl;dr: it mashes everything together so the class you're actually extending from is not an actual instance of `React.Component`. Which is most likely why you're getting this error.

Don't fight the language. The language doesn't support multi inheritance. May I suggest you use [composition over inheritance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA) instead?

Comment: Right, but shouldn't the instantiation of that Frankenstein class satisfy the requirements? From my understanding the methods are mounted properly to this new class.

Comment: @ColeyG no. a simple `instanceof` somewhere in the react code and this entire construct falls apart. because, it does not inherit from `React.Component`.